# Etymology of "Gedöns"

Tags: etymology, low-german

*Gedöns - kerfuffle, stuff, junk*

I don't expect this to appear in the most visible ety dictionaries.

Sadly I forgot what distant word prompted me to consider the question.

**Update**: Now after various hints towards dictionary entries, the question remains. The Duden enty is just a note, not an explanation. The de.Wiktionary entry is surprisingly extensive, linking it to Low German, referencing Pfeiffer and Kluge--and even Grimm notes a gloss, [gedense](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG03528#XGG03528), in which the word is already polysemous. Kluge is not accessible to me; An earlier edition, is archived online, that notes [gedunsen](https://archive.org/stream/etymologisches00klug#page/136/mode/2up) with a similar derivation akin to *dehnen*. [Pfeiffer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ged%C3%B6ns) qualifies the claim with "wohl", that is *probably* in my reading, so what's missing to be sure? Is "Rundung des Stammvokals zu ö" (rounding of the stem-vowel) not regular in Low German dialects?

After all, I can't verify the claim. I might be missing a strong argument in favor of this hypothesis. The arbitrariness of the development of any word towards a token of *randomness*, allows several interpretations of the material outlined above, that ends with the polysemous noun *gedense* and the allusion to *dinsen*.

That looks good, superficially, but not to the exclusion of other influences.

Comment: Is "carruffel" a commonly used word? Couldn't find it in dictionaries either, but I am highly amused by the fact that it is very close to the German dialect word "Geraffel", which basically means "stuff". As for Gedöns: I use it rather in the context of "ado, fuss".

Comment: First address for looking for etymology of a German word is very often Wolfgang Pfeiffer: _Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen_, which can be found digital and for free at dwds.de And it also has a Lemma _Gedöns_: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gedöns

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar updated. Indeed, I must have confused Ger. "Geraffel", which in Grimm's times they defined as "1. getöse, lärm, geräusch", i.e. *fuzz*, not merely "3. geräffel, unbrauchbares gerät, gerümpel", i.e. *junk*. That's pretty much the ambiguity I had in mind, and thus half-way in agreement with *kerfuffle*, "a disturbance or commotion typically caused by a dispute or conflict".

Comment: I must have thought of *tun* "to do", *Getue* "pretention, fuzz". Now I see *jäten* "to weed, weed out", of uncertain origin; It would make sense if *ziehen, zerren* was in there, i.e. "Unkraut zupfen"; Vice-versa, a development from *Unkraut* to *arbitrary nonsense, hustle, unwanted stuff* would make sense, depending on the origin of *jäten*. How does *weed* compare to *Gewese*?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you find anwers in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gedoens) and [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ged%C3%B6ns).

Duden:

> mittelhochdeutsch gedense = das Hin-und-her-Ziehen, das Gezerre, zu: dinsen, gedunsen

Wiktionary:

> Entlehnt aus dem Niederdeutschen Gedööns ‚Gerede, Gewese, Zeug‘, Entsprechung zu veraltetem Gedens(e) ‚schleppender Zug, Treck, Gezerre, Handgemenge‘, zu mittelhochdeutsch gedense ‚Herumziehen; Hin- und Herzerren‘, zu dinsen ‚ziehen, schleppen‘ gebildet.[1](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ged%C3%B6ns) Weitere siehe gedunsen.
>
> Das Wort erlangte im Deutschen ab 1998 eine größere Bekanntheit, als der damalige Bundeskanzlerkandidat Gerhard Schröder eine Ministerin suchte für das "Bundesministerium Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend", das er "Familie und das andere Gedöns" nannte, was später als abwertend rezipiert wurde. Es gibt unterschiedliche Versionen, wo und wann exakt er den Begriff prägte.[3][4][5][6][7]

Translation:

> Borrowed from the Niederdeutsch Gedööns 'Gerede, Gewese, Zeug' (Low German fuss), equivalent to outdated Gedens(e) 'schleppender Zug, Treck, Gezerre, Handgemenge' (dragging train, trek, tug, scuffle), to Middle High German fdense 'Herumziehen; Hin- und Herzerren' (dragging train, dragging train), to dinsen 'ziehen, schleppen' (dinsen) formed. Further see gedunsen.
>
> The word became more widely known in German in 1998 when Gerhard Schröder, the then Chancellor candidate, sought a minister for the "Bundesministerium Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend," which he called "Familie und das andere Gedöns," which was later received as derogatory. There are different versions of where and when exactly he coined the term.[3][4][5][6][7]

Comment: So, which of the senses of *gedense* should it be? I'd call that incomplete. Far better than nothing, but not satisfying, too implicit. Imaginably, *gedense* might already have meant *Gedöns* in figurative speech